# check result from prepared statements PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I use this code to get rows from database.

```
// Prepare WC statement
$queryUP = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM unitprices WHERE id_quot = :idQuotation");
// Execute Unit prices statement
$queryUP->execute(array(
 'idQuotation' => $idQuotation
));

// How to check the results is empty or not ?
if (results) { 
   // foreach($queryUP as $rowup) {
      //...
   // }
} else {
   // do another thing
}
```

I don't how to do to check if there is some results in the query before continuing the code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$queryUP = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM unitprices WHERE id_quot = ?");
$queryUP->execute(array($idQuotation));

//here you go
$results = $queryUP->fetchAll();

if ($results) { 
   // foreach($results as $rowup) {
      //...
   // }
} else {
   // do another thing
}
```

Hope you are doing your foreach in the template, not right in place as shown here.

Comment: if you are echoing anything inside the loop, it means not template is uses, while it should.

Comment: What is a template for you ?

Comment: A file where all HTML is writtern

Comment: Yes OK, in fact it's just a PHP which return a json, the php file is not used to update UI or something else

Comment: Then why don't you just json_encode the result right away, without foreach?

Answer (score 0):

If your memory allows you, you can fetch all:

```
$queryUP = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM unitprices WHERE id_quot = :idQuotation");
$queryUP->bindParam(':idQuotation', $idQuotation, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$queryUP->execute();
$result = $queryUP->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if (count($result) > 0) {
} else {
}
```